# Intellij - Use for html,js

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

Can `Intellij IDEA` IDE be used for `html and javascript`? As far as I can see, it does not render html properly.

And I saw Jetbrains has separate IDE(`webstorm`) for `js`. But that can be used for only 30 days(not free).

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely talking about community version of Intellij IDEA. This version doesn't support neither html nor javascript (or related techs like coffee script etc.).

All these are supported in ultimate (paid) version of Intellij.

See Intellij IDEA comparison matrix, Language Support section:

> Supported only in Ultimate Edition
>   HTML, CSS
>   JavaScript, CoffeeScript, TypeScript
>   ActionScript
>   Freemarker, Velocity

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Is there anything from Jetbrains for html, javascript that I can use for free?

Comment: There is no free product that has html and javascript features. If you work on an open source project, you might try applying for a license, see details here https://www.jetbrains.com/devnet/sponsorship/open-source/